# Instamojo Opencart

Tags: opencart, instamojo

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.2 version and I installed Instamojo Payment Gateway extension for my store, but during checkout instamojo payments method are not visible. What can be the reason for these?

Thanks

Comment: First, have you contacted the extension developer?

Comment: Yes, I did mail them and they said they will contact shortly.